# I have a csv file with time as the datetime format and want to edit the same column into only the relative miliseconds, how do I change that?

Tags: python, pandas

Input file is :

```
time event earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z

2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion -0.006379993 -0.001029071 -0.010781396

2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 motion 0.014739769 0.008146121 -0.001068155

2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion 0.008520941 -0.008222823 0.022573506

2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 motion 0.000573836 0.016701656 -0.016170829

2017-11-22T09:20:13.984 motion 0.016282924 0.003181049 0.006969224
```

I need to convert format of the first column and store new values in the same column.I need to remove the date and hours and just need the milliseconds of the time. Example : Time2 = time2- time1 i.e. I need relative time in milliseconds such that I can plot a graph by time.

Desired Output: (the time column should change into)

```
time 
0.01
0.012 
1.02 
1.04
```

The code I got is with a string input but how do I do with a whole column of a csv file, I cannot manually add those values.

```
from pandas import read_csv
from io import StringIO
csv_file = StringIO("""time event earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y 
earthAcceleration.z
2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion -0.006379993 -0.001029071 -0.010781396
2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 motion 0.014739769 0.008146121 -0.001068155
2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion 0.008520941 -0.008222823 0.022573506""")
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep=' ', parse_dates=['time'])
df.assign(delta_t = df.time-df.time.iloc[0])
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? `df.time.dt.microsecond.sub(df.time[0].microsecond).div(1000)  `

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅI guess if that works, but what I am concerned about is how do I apply this tot he whole column in a csv file

Comment: Uh, that _does_ work on the whole column, thanks to numpy broadcasting.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I ma super new to python can you write a sample code of how to use it? I would really appreciate that, thanks!

Comment: I _just_ did...

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want - I've made the code a bit more verbose than strictly necessary to make the steps clear:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from io import StringIO
csv_file = StringIO("""time event earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z
2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion -0.006379993 -0.001029071 -0.010781396
2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 motion 0.014739769 0.008146121 -0.001068155
2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion 0.008520941 -0.008222823 0.022573506""")
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep=' ', parse_dates=['time'])

#Additional code:
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
start_time = df.time.min()
df['millisecond_delta'] = (df['time'] - start_time)/dt.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

Comment: I want the specific column from csv file I can't enter values manually like you did as there are hundreds of them.How do i read a csv and change format of a certain column in the file

Comment: So you want to use `read_csv` exactly as you have there, but point it to the filename rather than your variable called 'csv_file'. Then pandas can change the format to datetime using the code `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` as I have used there. As an example, you might use `pd.read_csv('c:\users\filename.csv')`. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can tell you the arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, please tick the answer to let me know :) Just wanted to make sure you were clear on the distinction between the dataframe and the csv file, and the fact that pandas generally operates on whole columns ("vectorised" operation)

Comment: when I do what you say I get no ouput , writing my code again what i understood from you

Comment: from pandas import read_csv
from io import StringIO
csv_file = open('test.csv','r')
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep=' ', parse_dates=['time']):
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
start_time = df.time.min()
df['millisecond_delta'] = (df['time'] - start_time)/dt.timedelta(milliseconds=1)

Comment: I'd need to understand the nature of the error, Python doesn't do "no output"